# Add read more link into the end of a paragraph?

Tags: css, tumblr

I need to change read more link to be displayed at the end of the paragraph.

[image: img]

I need it to be like the **green paragraph**. Today it is like the red paragraph.

**Website: http://sindreolsson.tumblr.com - Check last post where I use read more.**

**CSS:**

```
.tumblr-text .rmlink { display: inline; }
```

**HTML**

```
{block:Text}
<!-- TEXT -->
<div class="tumblr-text">
{block:Title}<div class="title">{Title}</div>{/block:Title}
<div class="copy">{Body}
{block:More}<div class='rmlink'><a href="{Permalink}">Continue reading..</a></div>{/block:More}</div>
</div><!-- /.tumblr-text -->
{/block:Text}
```

Comment: Seems this issue is resolved: http://i.imgur.com/oLexZ5q.png

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I also had to disable the `<br>` tags in order to make it work, kind of like this:

```
.copy br {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a parent container with a fixed width, set the child elements to have `display: inline` to have them collapse like in-line text

```
.copy * {
    display: inline;
}
```

Of course, this will break the natural formatting of all previous `<p></p>` if you have more than one paragraph (which you don't want happening), so to preserve the original formatting, you only need to set the last element (specifically `<p>` elements) before the Read More break to have `display: inline`,
  i.e. the second-last child element if your Read More `<div>` is the last child.

But actually by the looks of it, tumblr likes to generate a set of empty `<p></p>` tags after the final element of the `{body}` text, so you'll need to account for the offset.

```
.copy > p:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) {
    display: inline;
}
```

This selects the immediate descedent `>` paragraph element `p` that is the last to second-last `(-n+2)` child of the type `:nth-last-of-type`. 
To clarify, `-n+2` in this scenario simply means select the last element, as well as the second-to-last element since you need to set the empty `<p></p>` that tumblr generates to `display: inline` as well as your actual last paragraph with content.

And then you can up the aesthetics with ellipsis if you want using additional CSS with the `::after` selector and `content:` set to the unicode escape for ellipsis (u2026).

```
.copy > p:nth-last-of-type(2)::after {
    content: "\2026";
}
```

---

**EDIT :**

Forgot to mention that this code alone will effect all posts that have `<p></p>`regardless of whether they contain the Read More break, and to only target those specific posts you need to modify the CSS to only apply to posts that have Read More links. One way to differentiate posts is to assign to the post a class name (e.g., `readmore`) wrapped around `{block:More}{/block:More}` block tags which only render on posts with Read More links.

**CSS**

```
.copy.readmore > p:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) {
    display: inline;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="copy{block:More} readmore{/block:More}">
    ...
</div>
```

Also, since Read More breaks are not rendered on the permalink page of the post, the CSS won't be applied there, and it will only be applied on index pages (your blog's main page) where the break occurs.

---

<kbd>[:nth-last-of-type](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anth-last-of-type)</kbd>
<kbd>[::after](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/%3aafter)</kbd>
<kbd>[&hellip; - \2026](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-xml-entity-names-20140410/bycodes.html#U02026)</kbd>

Comment: I have tried this codes and they effect other paragraphs to. It seems impossible only to effect the read more link. Is there a way we can connect with login information so you can go inside my code at tumblr?

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now. If you want to only apply this on posts with Read More blocks, assign a class to text posts that have Read More links by enclosing them with `{block:More}{/block:More}`, then target that specific class for the CSS. Updated answer, see above.

Comment: Still not working for me? I add your code to my code above but will not work.